# If condition not working in my git workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following GitHub worflow code:

```yaml
- name: Check if the project is central
  id: projectcheck
  run: echo "::set-output name=central::${{ contains(github.event.inputs.project, 'central') }}"
      
- name: output
   run: echo ${{ steps.projectcheck.outputs.central }}     
   ---  here I am getting true/false correctly based on the input project but the below if conditions are not working              
      
- name: if central
  if: ${{ steps.projectcheck.outputs.central }}  == "true"
  run: echo "central"
      
- name: if not central
  if: ${{ steps.projectcheck.outputs.central }} == "false"
  run: echo "central"
```

How can I make the if expression work?

Comment: Welcome to SO @harshita N :) Please make sure you use code-formatting and paste errors you have faced along with what you've tried. Here are some general hints on how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try for testing

```
if: steps.projectcheck.outputs.central  == 'true'
```

Ìf `steps.projectcheck.outputs.central` is a [string literal](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals), you should not need `${{ }}`

Comment: This might be obvious to everyone already, but `true` must be singly quoted, `'true'`. I see that is in the linked definition of [string literal](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals), which I assumed I understood to mean *string*. Unquoted and double quoted literals do not work.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to look into [expressions in GitHub actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions)

`if` conditional is treated as an expression, hence no explicit `${{ <expression> }}` is needed and you can write it like [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) mentioned.

But it's a good rule of thumb to use expressions everywhere, I'd recommend writing it like this:

```yaml
if: ${{ steps.projectcheck.outputs.central == "true" }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue on my workflow and non of the solution works for me.

My code

```
name: CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  repoX: 'abc'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          Write-output $env:repoX
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    if: $env.repoX ==  ${{ github.ref_name }}
    steps:
      - run: Write-Output "Success"
```

Job **deploy** is starting regardless of the value of the `repoX` variable